# How to set precision on column names made by np.arange()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I made dataframe and set column names by using `np.arange()`. However instead of exact numbers it (sometimes) sets them to numbers like 0.300000004.

I tried both rounding entire dataframe and using `np.around()` on `np.arange()` output but none of these seems to work.
I also tried to add these at the top:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
```

Here is return statement of my function:

```
stepT = 0.1
%net is some numpy array
return pd.DataFrame(net, columns = np.arange(0,1+stepT, stepT),
                    index = np.around(np.arange(0,1+stepS,stepS),decimals = 3)).round(3)
```

Is there any function that will allow me to have these names as numbers with only one digit after comma?

Comment: check with format

Comment: you mean how exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: is there a way to do it without changing format to string?

Comment: Do the names have to be numbers (floats) instead of strings?  Display of floats comes up often,

Comment: Well they do not, but I'm curious if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apparent imprecision of floating point numbers comes up often.

```
In [689]: np.arange(0,1+stepT, stepT)                                                                  
Out[689]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
In [690]: _.tolist()                                                                                   
Out[690]: 
[0.0,
 0.1,
 0.2,
 0.30000000000000004,
 0.4,
 0.5,
 0.6000000000000001,
 0.7000000000000001,
 0.8,
 0.9,
 1.0]
 In [691]: _689[3]                                                                                      
 Out[691]: 0.30000000000000004
```

The numpy print options control how the arrays are displayed. but they have no effect when individual values are printed.

When I make a dataframe with this column specification I get a nice display.  (`_689` is ipython shorthand for the `Out[689]` array.)  It is using the array formatting:

```
In [699]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11)[None,:], columns=_689)                                       
In [700]: df                                                                                           
Out[700]: 
   0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0
0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
In [701]: df.columns                                                                                   
Out[701]: 
Float64Index([                0.0,                 0.1,                 0.2,
              0.30000000000000004,                 0.4,                 0.5,
               0.6000000000000001,  0.7000000000000001,                 0.8,
                              0.9,                 1.0],
             dtype='float64')
```

But selecting columns with floats like this is tricky. Some work, some don't.

```
In [705]: df[0.4]                                                                                      
Out[705]: 
0    4
Name: 0.4, dtype: int64

In [707]: df[0.3]                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Looks like it's doing some sort of dictionary lookup.  Floats don't work well for that, because of their inherent imprecision.

Doing an equality test on the `arange`:

```
In [710]: _689[3]==0.3                                                                                 
Out[710]: False
In [711]: _689[4]==0.4                                                                                 
Out[711]: True
```

I think you should create a list of properly formatted strings from the `arange`, and use that as column headers, not the floats themselves.

For example:

```
In [714]: alist = ['%.3f'%i for i in _689]                                                             
In [715]: alist                                                                                        
Out[715]: 
['0.000',
 '0.100',
 '0.200',
 '0.300',
 '0.400',
 '0.500',
 '0.600',
 '0.700',
 '0.800',
 '0.900',
 '1.000']
In [716]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11)[None,:], columns=alist)                                      
In [717]: df                                                                                           
Out[717]: 
   0.000  0.100  0.200  0.300  0.400  0.500  0.600  0.700  0.800  0.900  1.000
0      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10
In [718]: df.columns                                                                                   
Out[718]: 
Index(['0.000', '0.100', '0.200', '0.300', '0.400', '0.500', '0.600', '0.700',
       '0.800', '0.900', '1.000'],
      dtype='object')
In [719]: df['0.300']                                                                                  
Out[719]: 
0    3
Name: 0.300, dtype: int64
```